# OpenVZ container with different subnet public IP (using venet)

Tags: networking, routing, openvz, proxmox

I am using Proxmox 3.4 with OpenVZ and venet. In various servers, everything is working fine.

But in a new dedicated server, I cant ping my only container.

The **public IP** of the HN is **158.69.241.xxx** and for the container **149.56.179.xxx**.

**Routing table**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
149.56.179.xxx  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
158.69.241.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
0.0.0.0         158.69.241.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 158.69.241.xxx
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 158.69.241.255
        gateway 158.69.241.254
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

**Netfilter configuration**

```
$ iptables -t nat -L && iptables -t filter -L && iptables -t mangle -L

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: How did you configure networking in the container?

Comment: I did not configure the network inside it, because I can't access it. Normally proxmox does this automatically.

Comment: Great idea: I will enter in its console by `vzctl enter <id>`

Comment: That's it! The interface were not up inside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the tip of Michael Hampton, I entered in the console of my container and realized that the networking service were not running.

**[ Solution ]**

**Step 1:** access the container console with:

```
vzctl enter <id>
```

**Step 2:** inside it, check the network config with:

```
ifconfig -a
```

**Step 3:** if venet0:0 doesn't appear, restart your network with:

```
service networking restart
```